# DataGrid -> DataGridComboBoxColumn -> ItemsSource динамический источник

Tags: c#, wpf

Здравствуйте, как можно сделать привязку к **DataGridComboBoxColumn.ItemsSource** динамическую привязку:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainViewModel.MainList}"
```

почему то он так не заполняется действует только статическая привязка

```
ItemsSource="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StaticMainList}"
```

А мне нужно что бы список был в зависимости от текущих параметров.
Можно ли как то сделать такую `ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainViewModel.MainList}"` привязку для **DataGridComboBoxColumn** элемента **DataGrid**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всем спасибо, нашёл:
когда `<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AnyList}" ...>`  **ItemsSource** привязывается то поиск остальных элементов внутри **DataGrid** начинается как раз с точки **ItemsSource**, поэтому и не заполнялся список **DataGridComboBoxColumn** элемента, так как он его ни мог найти. что бы можно было видеть `MainViewModel.MainList` нужно изменить начальную точку поска элемента списка это делается так:

```
ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MainViewModel.MainList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
```

здесь перешли на самый вверх тоесть на точку `MainViewModel`, теперь `MainViewModel.MainList` виден и список **DataGridComboBoxColumn** заполнится.

Comment: Что-то не совсем понял Ваш пример. Сейчас бьюсь над аналогичной задачей. Может поможете мне http://hashcode.ru/questions/351243/c-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-datagridcomboboxcolumn

Answer (score 0):

К сожалению с DataGridView такого не делал. Я делал подобное для ListView. Делал давненько уже и, на скаолько я помню, если я указывал источник в файле разметки, то ничего не работало. А если в файле разметки я указывал поле структуры, а в конструкторе указывал коллекцию-источник, то все было вполне работоспособно и при изменении данных в коллекции источнике, эти изменения отображались и в ListView. Ниже приведу код, может окажется полезным.
Файл xaml:

```
<ListView Name="ListAttributes" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" >
   <ListView.View>
      <GridView>
         <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Аттрибут" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Attribute}"/>
         <GridViewColumn Width="120" Header="Семантика" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Semantic}"/>
      </GridView>
   </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Файл cs:

```
ObservableCollection<Att> _Attrs = new ObservableCollection<Att>();
// Конструктор
public MainWindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   ListAttributes.ItemsSource = _Attrs;
}
// Структура, описываающая объект
public class Att
{
    public String Attribute { get; set; }
    public String Semantic { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо!!! это ни то...